# Differentiate in ItemUpdated (ER) if file was edited or overwritted

Tags: 2010, document-library, event-receivers, spfile

I've an ItemUpdated Event Receiver, and I need to make different operations depending if the file was updated throw UI or overwritted. Is there any internal field that reflects this 2 different behaviors or any other way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the ItemUpdating ER the value `properties.AfterProperties["vti_contenttag"]` is `null` when the doc is added, overwritting another one.

This could be a way to go, not the best for sure, but still a working solution...

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is a seperate flag for this, maybe you can use BeforeProperties and AfterProperties to achieve some workaround, like checking if only the version is increased and no other field has changed, you can consider this case as overwritten, not fullprrof not the best way but maybe one of the solutions